Electric Flux in Curved Spacetime
I just started physics II (electricity and magnetism) and while learning about Gauss's law I came across this alternate definition on Wikipedia:
$$\Phi_E=c\oint_{S}F^{\kappa0}\sqrt{-g}\ dS_{\kappa}$$
Where $c$ is the speed of light, $F^{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic field tensor
$$F^{\mu\nu}= \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -E_{x}/c & -E_{y}/c & -E_{z}/c \\ 
E_{x}/c & 0 & -B_{z} & B_{y} \\ 
E_{y}/c & B_{z} & 0 & -B_{x} \\ 
E_{z}/c & -B_{y} & B_{x} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
and $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor $g_{ij}$. Below the statement of the formula the article explains the $dS_{\kappa}$ term, which I am unfamiliar with. I am assuming this is a differential form that is also a tensor, but I'm not sure.
$$dS_{\kappa}=dS^{ij}=dx^{i}dx^{j}$$
From what I understand about tensors, $F^{\kappa0}$ is just the first column of $F^{\mu\nu}$ since the zero in the second index holds the column constant.
$$F^{\kappa0}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
E_{x}/c \\
E_{y}/c \\
E_{z}/c
\end{bmatrix}$$
Going back to the initial integral, it seems like the shared index kappa implies using Einstein notation for $F^{\kappa0}$ and $dS_{\kappa}$.
$$F^{\kappa0}dS_{\kappa}=\sum_{m=0}^{3}{F^{m0}dS_{m}} =F^{00}dS_{0}+F^{10}dS_{1}+F^{20}dS_{2}+F^{30}dS_{3}$$
Which would mean
$$cF^{\kappa0}dS_{\kappa}=(0)dS_{0}+E_{x}dS_{1}+E_{y}dS_{2}+E_{z}dS_{3}$$
Which looks like the gradient of $\vec{E}$, stripped of its first component, dotted with $d\vec{S}$ (also lacking the first component),
i.e.
$$\nabla\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}$$
Which would mean that the initial definition of $\Phi_{E}$ can be re-written as
$$c\oint_{S}\sqrt{-g}F^{\kappa0}dS_{\kappa}=\oint_{S}\sqrt{-g}\nabla\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}$$
I'm just trying to get a grasp on this expression of Gauss's law, so I am not sure if what I did to the initial equation is even useful or correct, but I wanted to know if this is the right way to think about it.
I have a few questions (assuming I didn't already make any egregious mistakes I'm unaware of):
Why is $g$ negative under the root? would this not result in $\sqrt{-1}$ for the metric tensor of Euclidean space?
Is $\sqrt{-g}$ acting in a similar way to the Jacobian determinant used when integrating with a change of coordinates?
Why does $\kappa$ split int i and j when $dS_{\kappa}=dS^{ij}=dx^{i}dx^{j}$, and what exactly does this differential mean?
I just started learning more about tensors and I'm still not sure I fully understand. Any responses are appreciated. Also, I hope that I am posting this in the right place as the question relates heavily to physics, but I thought my specific questions pertain mostly to the mathematics of Gauss's law.


$E_{x}dS_{1}+E_{y}dS_{2}+E_{z}dS_{3} = \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}$, not $\nabla\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}$. 2. $g$ is defined as the determinant of the metric tensor, and for flat spacetime it is exactly $-1$, and that is why $-g$ is a positive quantity you can take a square root of. 3. Why does κ split int i and j when $dS_κ=dS^{ij}=dx^i dx^j$ - Consider an infinitesimal area element whose normal is in the $z$ direction. Then this area element would be $dS_z = dx dy$


Is $\sqrt{-g}$ acting in a similar way to the Jacobian determinant used when integrating with a change of coordinates? - Yes. See any book on general relativity, e.g. the one written by Schutz.

Are you familiar into Gauss law in its regular form (flat spacetime)? The formula you wrote is just a generalization of $\Phi_E = \oint_S \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}$ written in curvilinear coordinates

This question may be more suited in the physics stack exchange

How does the article explain $dS_{\kappa}$?

"Why is $g$ negative under the root?" In relativity the metric has signature $(-,+,+,+)$ which makes $g,$ the determinant of the metric tensor, negative. To get a positive value under the root sign, we therefore must use $-g.$
